# How to get a regex match for non-standard quadric equation in Python?

Tags: python, regex, math

How to get a regex match for non-standard quadric equation in Python? I have a text with lists of numbers and quadric equations and I need to match all the coefficients of quadric equation: quadric, linear and constant.

I get a match for quadric coefficient and linear coefficient but how to match free member or constant without including all the random numbers in the text? 
Example of a non-standard quadric equation in a text:

```
- 39 + 41x + 75x + 54 - 67x + 171 - 70x2 - 27 - 90 - 48x = 0
```

Random number list added that should not create a match

```
[17, 18, 20, 24, 35, 37, 38, 41, 44, 49, 50, 52, 56, 71, 75, 77, 78, 83, 85, 86, 90, 92, 99]
```

Here's what I have found:
quadric coefficient match:

```
pattern_quadric = r"(-*\+*\s*)([0-9]+)x2"
```

linear coefficient match:

```
pattern_linear = r"(-*\+*\s*)([0-9]+)x(?!2)"
```

But I still haven't figured out how to match the constant (without x or x2) without matching all the other numbers in the text. Do I include equation mark (=) somehow?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Good question. I just added it to the main question. :)

Comment: Can you format this question @SoftShell, not sure how it should be formatted.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the input text. So it's basically an equation inside a random text and I need to get a match for the equation constant and not for the other  numbers in the text.

Comment: @SoftShell I do apologize, but I'm not sure what you're looking for (esp. output), nor am I able to understand the issue you're experiencing. Perhaps you're wanting to match both values using one regex? `[-+]\s*(?:(\d+)x2|(\d+)x(?!\d))`

Comment: I'm confused about the "random number list" that you say should not create a match. Are you saying that you want to discard matches that contain those numbers? So for example `67x` would be a match, but not `75x`, because `75` appears in that list?

Comment: Good point! I have a text with numbers (including in lists) and also quadric equations. I need to match all the constants in the quadric equation without including all the rest of the numbers. The numbers in a list are not any way connected to the equation. I just need to sort out the right output.

Comment: If they're not in any way connected to the equation, then I'm afraid I still fail to see why they're being mentioned in the first place. What's their relevance here? Could you post your desired output for the example input you provided?

Comment: @SoftShell My advice is to parse the input into an expression using, let's say, Sympy (https://sympy.org). Then you can work with it as a mathematical expression (containing variables and operators) instead of a text expression. Grouping terms by exponents is then still a nontrivial problem, but at least you can work with it in a more meaningful way. By the way, if you go down that road, chances are good that someone has already worked out a solution; try to find the Sympy user forum (I forget where it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the quadratic equation first, then do extra processing on it to get your result. You can use this regex which I came up with for matching your use case:

```
const regex = /\s*([+-]?\s*\d+(x|x2)?\s*)+\s*=\s*([+-]?\s*\d+(x|x2)?\s*)+\s*/g;
```

This does a couple of things

1. Remove spaces everywhere possible (`\s*`)
2. Match +- (`[+-]?)` is they are present
3. Match any amount of digits (`\d+`)
4. Followed by `x` or `x2`.
5. Repeat the entire thing as many times as possible until you get to a equals sign (=)
6. Copy paste the thing to after the `=` sign to match equation members on the other side.

See it in action here: https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=113045

After you extract the quadratic equation itself, you can do another set of regex on the result, or parse it character by character.